# Pygame refuses to draw objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm working on a kind of platformer game. The code you'll see is just the beginnings of it. The problem is that for some reason pygame refuses to draw my objects onto the screen. Everything seems alright, and I don't even get any errors. Help would be much appreciated. :)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
width = 1280
height = 720
score = 0
'create window'
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
'sprite groups'
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 640
        self.rect.y = 360
        self.speed = 0
    def update(self):
        pass
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(blue)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 640
        self.rect.y = 395


p = Player()
all_sprites.add(p)
running = True
while running:
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your loop you need to include `screen.update()` so that each frame the screen actually refreshes:

```
while running:
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    screen.update()
```

Comment: Oh wow. Sorry about the super obvious mistake. Thanks for the answer!